# How to check if list of string contains (substring) value in EpiFind?

Tags: find, episerver, episerver-find

I have indexed an object which has a list of strings like ["ZZA-KL-2A", "ZZA-KL-ZZB"]. I want to search and get all items which starts with a certain 3 letter code. So I want to check each item in the list and check something like 'StartsWith'.

I can see from documentation that we have something like Match, MatchContained but nothing for start with for the list of string items.

Please note that this question is not related to ordinary string comparison in C# or LINQ before flagging the question.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a filter

```
var searchQuery = client.Search<MyContent>()
  .Filter(x => x.OrderNumber.StartsWith("Find"));
```

https://world.episerver.com/documentation/developer-guides/search-navigation/NET-Client-API/searching/Filtering/

Answer (score 1):

You may use `Prefix` or `PrefixCaseInsensitive`:

> ## Matching by beginning of a string (startsWith)
>
> The `Prefix` method lets you match by the beginning of a string. The
> following search matches blog posts titled *Find* and *Find rocks!* but
> not *find*, *Finding* or *Hello Find*.
>
> ```
> var searchQuery = client.Search<BlogPost>().Filter(x =>
> x.Title.Prefix("Find"));
> ```
>
> Use the `PrefixCaseInsensitive` method to match by the beginning of a
> string in a case-insensitive way. The following search matches blog
> posts titled *Find*, *Find rocks!* and *Find* but not *Finding* or *Hello Find*.
>
> ```
> var searchQuery = client.Search<BlogPost>().Filter(x =>
> x.Title.PrefixCaseInsensitive("Find"));
> ```

Source: https://docs.developers.optimizely.com/digital-experience-platform/v1.1.0-search-and-navigation/docs/strings#matching-by-beginning-of-a-string-startswith